# Properly formatted MySQL date insert statement returns all 0's

Tags: php, mysql, date

I've created a PHP script that parses an HTML page, creates a MySQL query, and inserts the parsed data into a MySQL table. Everything works fine, except for one thing : the date field. When PHP runs the MySQL statement, the dates in the table read 0000-00-00 . If I echo the MySQL query, it results in the following :

```
INSERT INTO dispatch_table (dispatch_date, dispatch_time, dispatch1, dispatch2, dispatch3, dispatch4, dispatch5, dispatch6, dispatch7, dispatch8, dispatch9, dispatch10, dispatch11, dispatch12, dispatch13, dispatch14, dispatch15, dispatch16)VALUES ('2010-02-02', '10:46:17', '31.90' , '32.15','32.24','32.39','33.46','35.18','39.33','39.39','40.92','41.79','41.82','44.35','45.47','46.89','47.13','67.59');
```

If I copy and paste the statement into the MySQL table, it inserts the date just fine, but when PHP trys to insert it, I am given all 0's. The dispatch_date field is a "date" field in MySQL. Before inserting the dates with the PHP code, the date to insert is converted to a string (I thought this might solve my problem). Can anyone give me any insight on this?

Comment: More PHP code we see, the more insight we can give you.

Answer (score 1):

From tizag.com

> When you enter dates that are out of
>   the range or in the wrong format for a
>   given date type, MySQL will often just
>   enter in the default value of all
>   zeros.

You are storing them in the wrong format.

Comment: It could be because you are converting the date to a "string" and then inserting it into a "date" column.

Answer (score 0):

2010-02-02 (%Y-%m-%d) is the default format but it can be changed. Run this query to learn what the values are in your server:

```
SELECT @@date_format, @@datetime_format;
```

If they don't match, you'll have to either change your queries or change the @@date_format and @@datetime_format variables. They can be changed in a per-session basis:

```
SET @@session.date_format='%Y-%m-%d';
SET @@session.datetime_format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s';
```