# Date in My SQL always 0000-00-00

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been both tearing my hair and sacrificing to the gods - and doing what homework I can YET  I have the same problem as two other posts here both of which appear unresolved they are

[Properly formatted MySQL date insert statement returns all 0's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185392/properly-formatted-mysql-date-insert-statement-returns-all-0s)

and

[MYSQL Date field always outputs 0000-00-00](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10974066/mysql-date-field-always-outputs-0000-00-00)

when I echo I get properly formatted values I am using Date not DATETIME MySQL properly enters a name prior to the date but then ALSO enters a blank longblob (picture) - It would seem that either it is only entering one field or somehow I have not got the MySQL set up properly or something else?

my code is

```
catch(PDOException $e)
    {
    echo "Im sorry dave I cant do that";
    echo $e->getMessage();
    }

        //*next bit is to insure that if connection is lost database is not  
   partially updated-I think-
        //* $DBHandle->beginTransaction();

        $firstnameOBS= $_POST['touristfirstname'];
        $todaysdateOBS= $_POST['touristdatetoday'];
        $picturenow= $_POST['picturesubmitted'];

        $JSONfirstname = json_encode($firstnameOBS);
        $JSONtodaysdate = json_encode($todaysdateOBS);
        $JSONpicturenow = json_encode($picturenow);
        echo $JSONtodaysdate ;

        //* Below is the send from PHP page to My Sql Server -
                //*  JSON encode here 

    try {    
        $senditin = $DBHandle->prepare("INSERT INTO 
    `Observations`.`fkarnd`(`firstname`,`datetoday`,`picturesubmitted`) VALUES   
 (:firstname 
    , :datetoday ,:picturesubmitted)", array(PDO::ATTR_CURSOR => PDO::CURSOR_FWDONLY));

        //* $senditin->bindValue(':firstname', $JSONfirstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //* $senditin->bindValue(':datetoday', $JSONtodaysdate, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        //* $senditin->bindValue(':picturesubmitted', $JSONpicturenow,
     PDO::PARAM_LOB);

        //* $myinputarray = array('firstname'=> $JSONfirstname, 'datetoday' => 
    $JSONtodaysdate, 'picturesubmitted' => $JSONpicturenow );

        $DBHandle->beginTransaction();
        $senditin->execute(array('firstname'=> $JSONfirstname, 'datetoday' => 
    $JSONtodaysdate, 'picturesubmitted' => $JSONpicturenow ));
        //* commit allows transaction begun to complete
        $DBHandle->commit();

     }  

    catch ( PDOException $e ) {
      echo "I'm sorry, I can't do that Dave......";
      file_put_contents( 'dbErrors.txt', $e->getMessage(), FILE_APPEND );   
        //* rollback function call here? a nasty exception has appeared,      
     }
        echo "<br>"."successful submission";
        $DBHandle = null;

     ?>
```

Comment: What is the value before you call `json_encode()` on it? That is probably going to return a quoted string, which is not a date, and will be cast as 0, resulting in all zero dates.  What's your reason for calling `json_encode()` on any of those values?

Comment: what is the datatype of your database row?

Comment: You mean that JSON encode will change the data type? The echo looks the same before and after the JSON encode (mainly I think because in an effort to get things to work I am imputing data yyyy-mm-dd and I use 2002 02 02 so if month and year are transposed its ok.

Comment: Data type of field is DATE

Comment: calling JSON encode to obviate possible injection

Comment: json_encode doesnt return the correct string format.

Comment: what are the date values you're sending to the db. mysql expects `yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss`. if you send pretty much anything else, mysql will default to the all 0's date value.

Comment: use datetime for your database

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean to call json_decode($todaysdateOBS) instead?  It looks like this might be the source of the issue, as json_encode will try to encode in json format whatever you send to it, which is not a valid date field in sql (http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: I am trying to input data into the DB thus I am encoding data before submission to the DB. If I were pulling it out I would use decode? I will try to change the MySQL DB field from a DATE type to a String? but this seems counter to why I would use JSON...?

Comment: it makes sense if you use the string type for mysql db. but you'll ofcourse lose out on datetime functions inbuilt

Comment: OK Close this Puppy - Thanks folks - without the JSON works fine.... will have to address that issue another way. THANKS

Comment: @DPR-treasureisland you have to approve an accepted answer, that's how the post gets closed